# list in android

Tags: java, android, android-emulator, android-widget, android-manifest

How do I put image and name in the list in Android?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use a custom list adapter.

Here are few links that might be useful..

http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/how-update-custom-listview-images-simply

http://androidgenuine.com/?tag=text-and-image-on-a-listview-android

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a ListAdapter to tell the ListView how to display your items (image and name). [You can read a tutorial here.](http://developerlife.com/tutorials/?p=327) I'm sure there are many other tutorials out there, [including the ones from google](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-listview.html).